# Difference between internal and external memory speed on Android

Tags: android, performance

I have a question about the actual speed difference between the internal and disk memory of Android devices.
It has been asked in SO 15698747, but without specific answer. I know the facts, discussed there, but I would like to get some (at least rough) data. Has anybody measured actual speed differences? To be more specific:

1/ If the disk memory is emulated portion of the internal memory (like on NEX4, NEX5 ...), is there a considerable difference?

2/ Has anybody checked the difference between the internal memory and SD cards class 4,6,10 ...? I know that different devices will start with different internal memory speed, but any estimate will be good.

Rough multiples (how many times is the internal memory faster) would suffice.

Comment: "If the disk memory is emulated portion of the internal memory (like on NEX4, NEX5 ...), is there a considerable difference?" -- there should be no significant difference. It is the same filesystem on the same flash memory.

Comment: @CommonsWare thank you. (Any takers for question #2?)